# Locking MySQL account if inactive for a certain time

Tags: mysql

Can some one please tell how MySQL can be set up so that human user accounts are locked if inactive for “x” number of days.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You could schedule some job that would check and turn off permissions. MySQL even supports scheduling: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/events-overview.html

Comment: How would any mechanism know if the user was human?

Answer (score 0):

if in a linux server you can do this by crontab, and make a simple script for check accounts  that have long time inactives.

i have done this easy in php.
just a php file with a easy php/sql script you can check date of last login of some account, and disable it if no longer used.
run script from simple shell command "#php /scriptfolder/script.php"